# Problem booting using Live USB on MAC

Tags: linux, boot, macintosh

I have tried creating a bootable Linux USB that i want to use on *MacBook Pro 2013*.

1. I used 'MAC Linux USB Loader' to do that.
2. Linux distros I tried it with: Slack puppy and DSL (Damn small linux)
3. Flash Drive/USB: 512MB, 1024bytes FAT32 MBR formatted on windows, MAC doesn't do FAT32 for some reason.

When I boot through MAC Alt/Option, it shows EIF drive, boots a bit and then I get this error:

```
Kernel path: /live/vmlinuz | ramdisc path: /live/initrd.lz 
boot parameters: 

Loading Linux kernel... done
unaligned pointer 0x2. 
Aborted.
```

I get this same error when booting any of the above mentioned OS.
I have tried literally *all* other approaches of creating bootable Linux USB and none of them worked - Mac don't even show EIF drive on 'Alt' booting in these scenarios.

I have tried many other tools listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_to_create_Live_USB_systems) for MAC, but they don't detect my USB itself.